# Curl easy handle not able to resolve host after ~10 minutes of inactivity?

Tags: c++, curl, https, libcurl

I have initialized `curlHandle` using `curl_easy_init()` and have set some options eg. url, type of request, timeout, ssl verification etc.

I read that re-using same curlHandle increases performance and did little sample code writting as well, it happened to be true.

So I initialized handle once in the constructor of my class and then resuing the same handle every time just changing header or request, but if I do not use that `curlHandle` for 10 minutes and then if I try to reuse then it throws an exception that could not resolve host.

Is there the time limit for which you can use `curlHandle`?
Because I did not see any such mention in any SO question or curl documentation.
Or is it like after certain timeout you have to do `curl_easy_init()` again?

[EDIT]

I am using wolfSSL for SSL communication with cURL.

By default session-id caching is disabled in wolfSSL and enabled in curl
because of `CURLOPT_SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE` defaulting to 1.

Session-id times out after inactivity of 500 seconds( Approx. 8 minutes) whereas cURL tries to reuse the same session-id. 
This is causing the failure in `SSL_set_session` of wolfSSL and this causes curl to fail after 8-10 minutes of inactivity.

Curl version used 7.49.1

Comment: Did you test HTTP server timeout, for instance with `telnet`? Perhaps the server disconnects you in case of inactivity.

Comment: I have a doubt that .. that is the reason I am not again able to make call ...

Comment: So lets say server disconnects me after 10 mins of inactivity , do i need to reset handle to again connect ?

Comment: If server disconnects you, then the socket is closed and another one has to be created and connect. `curl_easy_reset()` description says that it "puts back the handle to the same state as it was in when it was just created with curl_easy_init." So, I would say you need to reset it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no time limit for a curl handle and no, it is not supposed to cause any particular errors after having been idle for ten or more minutes. If you can reproduce this with a recent version of libcurl, it might be a bug...

Comment: I have modified question by adding the detailed analysis of failure. 
Is this expected behaviour of curl or this is a genuine issue?

Comment: Yeah ... seems the same ... will do full testing with latest version... and if still able to reproduce will file a defect in curl's github page... thanks for responding